# Boolean Tick Box Not Changing Overall Cost (PHP)

Tags: php, parsing, checkbox, boolean

I have parsed over the variable $museum from another page under the name 'm'. If a check box was ticked on the page I parsed it from then on this new receipt page it will add 5 to the cost, or add 0. Cost is then echoed. But either way it is returning 0. First time poster and PHP beginner so sorry if I got something wrong or was not specific enough. Here is the code from the receipt page.

```
<?php

$cost = 0;

if(isset($_GET['m']))
{
$museum = $_GET['m'];
if($museum==false){ 
$cost + 0;
}else{
$cost + 5;
}
}

echo $cost;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the return value of the operation. Try

```
$cost += 5;
```

instead of

```
$cost + 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($museum==false){ 
$cost = $cost + 0;
}else{
$cost = $cost + 5;
}
```